# If $M_n \to M_{\infty}$ in $\mathscr L^{2}$, then inequality holds with equality

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, martingales, integral-inequality

From Williams' Probability with Martingales

---

[image]

---

I tried rewriting the RHS to:

$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} E[(M_k - M_{k-1})^2] = \sum_{k=n+1}^{n+r} E[(M_k - M_{k-1})^2] + \sum_{k=n+r+1}^{\infty} E[(M_k - M_{k-1})^2]$$

$$ = E[(M_{n+r} - M_n)^2] + \sum_{k=n+r+1}^{\infty} E[(M_k - M_{k-1})^2]$$

Now let $r \to \infty$.

How is $f$ used? Is it used in justifying

$$\lim_r E[(M_{n+r} - M_n)^2] = E[\lim_r(M_{n+r} - M_n)^2]$$

$$\big( = E[(M_{\infty} - M_n)^2] \big)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $r\ge 0$
$$
\mathbb{E}(M_{\infty}-M_n)^2=\mathbb{E}(M_{\infty}-M_{n+r})^2+\mathbb{E}(M_{n+r}-M_n)^2 \\\overset{(d)}=\mathbb{E}(M_{\infty}-M_{n+r})^2+\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+r}\mathbb{E}(M_k-M_{k-1})^2.
$$

Taking $r\to\infty$, the first term converges to $0$ by (f).

Comment: Thanks d.k.o. 1 Why exactly does $f$ make the first term converge to $0$ ? 2 How about my approach?

Comment: It is exactly the limit in (f)...

Comment: oh lol thanks. Thought you did have to use Pythagorean theorem not sure how that's obvious

Comment: What do u mean?

Comment: the book said 'of course' but it doesnt come to mind to use Pythagorean